# toilet handle prevents flapper from closing sometimes

Tags: toilet

My toilet "sometimes" runs water incessantly after flushing.  Upon examination it appears it's because the handle, after flushing, descends and then gets in the way of the flapper closing, holding it open forever.  If I hold it for quite awhile when flushing, then let go, it works OK, but I'd prefer to be able to "flush and leave" as it were.

I looked at other questions here and didn't seem to find a precise match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to tighten the handle.  It was allowing the handle arm to descend "all the way to the ground" which happens to interfere with the flapper.  But these handles are apparently designed in such a way that they aren't supposed to allow the handle "get too low ever" so if your handle is "pointing straight down" you have a problem.  Mine was fixed by tightening it up again.

Requisite diagram to show arm vs. handle:

[image]